# ¿Cómo hacer que recorra el array correctamente en ésta función JS y desactive un botón?

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código escrito para que me haga un función filtrando 3 códigos postales y que de un error cuando sean introducidos en un campo Input text pero solamente me lee el 35 primero y valida si el CP introducido en el campo input es correcto o no en base al 35 pero no a los otros 2 CP. almacenados en *codigosPostalesInvalidos*; tampoco me desactiva un botón cuando el CP. introducido sea uno de esos 3, acceso por JQ por name al input y por id al botón.

```
<input class="form-control orig-field live -former-error -error" name="postcode" type="text" value="51" placeholder=" " required="">
<button id="confirm_order" type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block" data-link-action="x-confirm-order">
      <div class="minimal-purchase-error-msg"></div>
      <div class="tc-loader"><div class="lds-ellipsis-m"><div><div></div></div><div><div></div></div><div><div></div></div><div><div></div></div><div><div></div></div></div></div>
              Continuar
          </button>

var codigosPostalesInvalidos = [35, 52, 51]; //cp a filtrar
function validarCp(codigoPostal){
    for (let i=0; i<=codigosPostalesInvalidos.length-1; i++) {
        cadena=(codigoPostal.substring(0,2));
            if (parseInt(cadena)==codigosPostalesInvalidos[i]){
                //Código postal no válido;
                return false;
            }else{
                //Código postal válido;
                return true;
            }
        }
    
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='postcode']").change(function() {
        resultado = validarCp($("input[name='postcode']").val())
        if (resultado){
            $('.clase0071').text('ok');
            console.log("VÁLIDO");
        }else{
            $('.clase0071').text('Ha introducido un código postal donde no realizamos envios, NO ES POSIBLE CONTINUAR LA COMPRA.');
            $("#confirm_order").attr("disabled");
            console.log("NO VÁLIDO");
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que cuando entras en el bucle *for*, pase lo que pase (*if* o *else*), haces un *return*, con lo que en la primera iteración siempre va a devolverte ya una respuesta sin validar el resto de los elementos del array. Por eso se comporta bien con el primero de los números (35) y mal con los demás.

Te dejo el código corregido. Es simplemente quitar el *else*, y si una vez acabado el bucle *for* no ha entrado en el *return*, entonces ahora sí le damos un *return true*.

```js
var codigosPostalesInvalidos = [35, 52, 51]; //cp a filtrar
function validarCp(codigoPostal){
    for (let i=0; i<=codigosPostalesInvalidos.length-1; i++) {
        cadena = codigoPostal.substring(0,2);
        if(parseInt(cadena) == codigosPostalesInvalidos[i]){
            //Código postal no válido;
            $('#boton').attr('disabled',true);
            return false;
        }
     }
     $('#boton').attr('disabled',false);
     return true;
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='postcode']").change(function(){
    resultado = validarCp($("input[name='postcode']").val())
 console.log('resultado',resultado);
 if (resultado){
            $('.clase0071').text('ok');
            console.log("VÁLIDO");
        }else{
            $('.clase0071').text('Ha introducido un código postal donde no realizamos envios, NO ES POSIBLE CONTINUAR LA COMPRA.');
            $("#confirm_order").attr("disabled");
            console.log("NO VÁLIDO");
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control orig-field live -former-error -error" name="postcode" type="text" value="" placeholder=" " required="">

<button id="confirm_order" type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block" data-link-action="x-confirm-order">Continuar</button>

<input type="button" id="boton" value="Botón"/>

<div class="minimal-purchase-error-msg"></div>
<div class="tc-loader"><div class="lds-ellipsis-m"><div>
```